# HTML - How to make button text change after certain amount of time

Tags: html

I have 6 buttons called button1, button2, button3, and so on. The text on each of the buttons is "button one", "button two", and so on. When you click on the buttons, it makes the button's text change. I want the text to stay the way for about 5 seconds, and then change back to what it was before. I've looked at some other questions on Stack Overflow but none of them have answered my question. Thanks

Comment: You'll want to look at using Javascript to do this. Listen for the click event, save the current button content, set a "setTimeout" timer to change whatever the button's content is back to the original content after 5 seconds, and then change the button text to the temporary new value...

Comment: Can you write that out?

Comment: Can anyone write that out?

Answer (score 0):

If not already done, you need to add an `id` to each button, like so:

```
<button id="button1">button 1</button>
```

To change the button text just using JS:

```
<script>
function changeText(button, text, textToChangeBackTo) {
  buttonId = document.getElementById(button);
  buttonId.textContent = text;
  setTimeout(function() { back(buttonId, textToChangeBackTo); }, 5000);
  function back(button, textToChangeBackTo){ button.textContent = textToChangeBackTo; }
}
</script>
```

To call the function, simply add an `onClick` to each button, like so:

```
<button onClick="changeText('button1', 'button clicked', 'button 1');" id="button1">button 1</button>
```

So the final code would be:

```html
    <button onClick="changeText('button1', 'button clicked 1', 'button 1');" id="button1">button 1</button>
    <button onClick="changeText('button2', 'button clicked 2', 'button 2');" id="button2">button 2</button>
    <button onClick="changeText('button3', 'button clicked 3', 'button 3');" id="button3">button 3</button>
        <script>
    function changeText(button, text, textToChangeBackTo) {
      buttonId = document.getElementById(button);
      buttonId.textContent = text;
      setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById(button).textContent = textToChangeBackTo; }, 5000);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me and still rocking the HTML 4.01 and need a quick way to switch the button value tag like below...

```
value="dingos"
```

switch the

```
.textContent to .value
```

Comment: The HTML5 tag suggests the question is specific to HTML 5 and not 4.01.